# multiframe tiff splitting in linux

Tags: linux, image, .net-core

I have a tiff with multiple pages.
This is my code, and it works **perfectly** on Windows

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;   
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("image.tiff");
int count = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
{
    bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, idx);
    bitmap.Save($"{idx}.jpg");
}
```

But if I run this code on linux it exports all the times the first frame, so seems it can read only first frame.
The **count** var displays correctly the number of frames.
If you want a sample file you can download it from here http://www.nightprogrammer.org/wp-uploads/2013/02/multipage_tiff_example.tif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed with ImageMagick library

```
using (MagickImageCollection tiffImageCollection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    tiffImageCollection.AddRange("image.tiff");
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var img in tiffImageCollection)
    {
        img.Write(count + ".jpg");
        count++; 
    }
}
```